# Specify specific address when uploading blobs to windows azure

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using .Net. Is it possible to specify specific address for blobs when you upload blobs to window azure storage?

Because I want to have the link to the file before the file finishes uploading. I don't care if the link don't work, I just want to have the link first.

I heard that this is possible, but I couldn't find any reference to it. I was told to generate the file identifier and then upload the file with that identifier.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this answer straight from guide on windowsazure.com.  It was the #1 result for the phrase "upload file to azure blob storage" in google.

I believe that in the `GetBlockBlobReference` method you can substitute "myblob" with the whatever you want the blob file name to be.

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I misunderstood that concept. I've seen that guide many times... and problem is solved.

Comment: I knew you could do it because I use [Azure Storage Explorer] (http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/) to upload files to my blob storage, and you can specify the filename.  Good tool to have, you should try it out (and no, I am in no way affiliated with it other than the fact I use it).